# How to initialize/run a java project in maven plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, maven, project

I am now writing a maven plugin. The purpose of this plugin is to call and initialize another java project which I have previously written. Anyone knows how I can acheive this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is an existing [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) which provides a goal [java](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) that can be use to run Java programs from a plugin. Maybe this is what you need - otherwise explain your use case a bit more detailed.

Comment: Hi,
I am planning to use Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec() to launch my java project. however, i do not know how to do it
should i write it as Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -classpath Cclasspath) (arguments) (mainclass)")?
thanks for the help

Comment: @ken Maybe you should have a look at the source code of the exec-maven-plugin ([ExecJavaMojo.execute](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec/ExecJavaMojo.java#ExecJavaMojo.execute)). They load the class and invoke the main Method by reflection. If the class is not on your classpath have a look at the [Apache Commons Exec library](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) which provides functionality to execute external processes.

Comment: @Claszen I have looked at the source code for execJavaMojo, however the biggest problem which I have now is that I need to feed in VMarguemts in order to initialize my java project. I have no clue how to do this.
Once again, thanks!